# If programs depend on system calls to perform important tasks how can they run on different oss?

Tags: operating-system, system

If i understood correctly programs depend on system calls to perform tasks like creating files, create new process, and stuff like that.

How can programs run on different os?

Are system calls standarised?

Answer (score 0):

It's a linking process that actually resolve missing symbols after compilation. When you cross compile something or compile any software for other platform. Than you have to provide that symbol table.
That symbol table consist of many library components and system call table. So, they are specific (and different) for each OS. System calls are indirectly called by library functions.
Try to compile any C program with this command (It should call some type of system call, like call malloc function).

```
gcc -c -nostdlib main.c -o main.o
```

This will create object file with no OS (target) specific library and without linking (-c flag).
After that look at the symbols of output ELF.

```
readelf --symbols main.o | grep "UND"
```

You will see unresolved symbols.